# Jquery: can't select Video tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, drupal-theming

I have a video element inside a div. I just want set the video height to the full windows. I swear it was working, but in some moment I broke, and don't understand why ...

The jQuery selector has length=0, maybe because the videos are loading after jQuery make the selections, but till 2 days ago was working

```js
var $current_height = $(window).height();
var $videohome = $('video');
$videohome.height($current_height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video full_height center"><a href="page">
      <video class="full_height" poster="sites/all/themes/my_theme/img/cover_video1.jpg" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.load()"  id="video1" loop="true">
        <source src="sites/default/files/videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <source src="sites/default/files/videos/video1.ogg" type="video/ogg"></source>
      </video></a>
</div>
```

notes:

- are others videos in the page, but I guess for example only 1 is ok
- this code is working with other kind of elements in the page (divs, for example)
- Using: Drupal 7.41, jQuery 1.4.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `$videohome.height($current_height);` called ? Before jQuery loaded ?

Comment: No, even in the same line, if I select other DOM element rather than video, is working

Comment: Try using `.ready()` . See post

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `js` within `$(document).ready(function() {})` , see [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $current_height = $(window).height();
  var $videohome = $("video");
  $videohome.height($current_height);
  $videohome[0].load();
  $videohome[0].play(); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="video full_height center">
  <video class="full_height" id="video1" controls loop="true">
    <source id="currentVID" src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Because Drupal 7 best practices I avoided $(document).ready() 
Here you can see the file: http://dev.hedmon.com/ronzak/sites/all/themes/ronzak_theme/js/ronzak.js
and here the problem http://dev.hedmon.com/ronzak/

Comment: Ah! the most important: Thank you very much for you help!! ;)